# Double tennis serve hits opponent purposely

Tags: tennis, serve

From the video [Jelena Ostapenko hits Alize Cornet with a serve and wins point! | Wimbledon 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHsOkBl1wRE), we can see that the serve has given a point. I wonder if they revenge back by serving the tennis ball back by hitting the player, and make the whole game like dodgeball. What would happen after all?

Comment: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15345/are-there-any-rules-in-tennis-regarding-deliberately-aiming-the-ball-at-the-play

Answer (score 0):

Hitting the opponent/ball kid/empire intentionally is unsportsmanlike conduct and can get one anywhere from a  warning to being disqualified. BUT, deciding whether it was intentional is up to the chair empire . A one-off occurrence is highly unlikely to be judged intentional

Comment: Too small to edit: of / off